# iOS appendFomat cause app to crash

Tags: ios

Is there anything wrong with the code below ? It crash my app sometimes.

```
- (NSString*) getDisplayString
{
    NSMutableString* display = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [entries count]; i++)
{
    Entry* e = [entries objectAtIndex:i];
    [display appendFormat:@"%d. %@ %30d\n", i+1, e.title, e.value];

}

    return display;
}
```

Comment: Post the crash details, and (not related) you need to autorelease display.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to replace %30d with %d.

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom there is nothing wrong with %30d. It just specifies a length of 30 for the format.

Comment: The entry object just hold a NSString and a NSUInteger. What is very strange the same collection in entries will not always cause the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem. Issue is memory management where I wasn't increasing the retain count of the NSString title found in the Entry object. title is the value obtain from user input through a textfield so when the UIView is releasing the string which is done internally, its no longer in memory hence it makes the error appears to be random.

So to summarise whenever u are using a value from a textfield, you need to increase its retain count.

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString* someStringToStore = uiTextField.text;
[someStringToStore retain];
[myArray addObject: someStringToStore];
```